# Как поменять или добавить цвета в bootstrap 4 в файле variable.scss

Tags: sass, scss, bootstrap4

я видел в bootstrap 4 есть и другие цвета https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/theming/#sass-options

Расскажите пожалуйста по подробнее как их можно применить

Пример : text-dark работает 
         text-indigo  нет..
заранее спасибо !

Answer (score 0):

Если скачать bootstrap.zip и открыть в нем css/bootstrap.css вы увидите:

```
:root {
  --blue: #007bff;
  --indigo: #6610f2;
  --purple: #6f42c1;
  --pink: #e83e8c;
  --red: #dc3545;
  --orange: #fd7e14;
  --yellow: #ffc107;
  --green: #28a745;
  --teal: #20c997;
  --cyan: #17a2b8;
  --white: #fff;
  --gray: #6c757d;
  --gray-dark: #343a40;
  --primary: #007bff;
  --secondary: #6c757d;
  --success: #28a745;
  --info: #17a2b8;
  --warning: #ffc107;
  --danger: #dc3545;
  --light: #f8f9fa;
  --dark: #343a40;
...
```

Это константы фирменных цветов но не все из них используются ниже
Для того чтобы использовать **.text-indigo** и другие придется дописать описание этих классов.

```
<style>
    .text-indigo{
        color: var(--indigo);
     }
</style>

<h1 class="text-indigo">Hello, world!</h1>
```

Или сделать свою сборку проекта например через **webpack**, но это будет посложнее.